# (ListView?)-Control like in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, listview

I'm wondering if there is any way to make a control like that one in windows explorer's auto start when you plugin a device.

[image]

I had thought that this could be a listview-control in a more or less modified way, but I was not able to find anything with Google. I also checked many CodeProject-pages.

Does anyone have an idea where I would be able to get the control or how I could make one myself? (I am not that good with OwnerDraw :P)

Thanks.

Comment: Winforms or WPF? It is easy to create it in WPF, and not so hard in Winforms.

Comment: It is normal WinForms.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it, @MD.Unicorn?

Comment: Pretty sure that this ***is*** a ListView. Have you tried using one already? OwnerDraw should be unnecessary. You will need to apply the Explorer theme, though: [.NET ListView and Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1936179)

Comment: Great! Yes, I tried it.
I will have a look at it and try to make my own user control which inherits from a ListView.

Then with applying that it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually tweaking a `ListView` is not any easier than ownerDrawing it. Here is an example that shows, how simple it really is.

You just script one event (`DrawItem`) and you are done.

This piece of code assumes:

- The LV's View is set to List
- You have a suitable ImageList added to your form
- You have the LV's ownerDraw set to true
- You have added two columns to hold the text shown in the two labels
- You have made the 1st column wide enough to hold the whole stuff that gets drawn
- You have made the LV's FontSize as large as the Images' Height (say 32)
- Assign the appropriate ImageIndex values to the LV's Items

---

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  Point point0 = new Point(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top);
  Point point1 = new Point(imageList1.ImageSize.Width + 10, e.Bounds.Top + 5);
  Point point2 = new Point(imageList1.ImageSize.Width + 10, e.Bounds.Top + 25);
  Size size = new Size(listView1.ClientRectangle.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
  Rectangle R = new Rectangle(point0, size);
  Font F1 = new Font(listView1.Font.FontFamily, 11f, FontStyle.Bold);
  Font F2 = new Font(listView1.Font.FontFamily, 10f);

  if (e.Item.Focused) e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, R);
    else if (e.ItemIndex % 2 == 1) e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.GhostWhite, R);
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex], point0 );
  e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, F1, Brushes.Black, point1);
  e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.SubItems[1].Text, F2, Brushes.Black, point2);
  F1.Dispose(); F2.Dispose();
}
```

Note that I have hard-coded a few Colors to paint every other line and also the focused item. These colors really should use the respective System colors. These come to mind:

```
 SolidBrush brush0 = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlLight);
 SolidBrush brush1 = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight);
```

I am using the Font that is assigned to the LV but with moderate sizes. Obviously more or less anything, especially the various offsets, can be configured to your liking. But using colors from the `System.Colors` collection is good way to stay in keeping with your users' Windows themes.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please put that code in code tags?

Comment: Well ok, thanks though :). I used your code.
I can't figure out what you mean with the columns or better said what I have to do with them.

Comment: A ListView can have a columns collection. (aka subitems). visible only in Detail View but having them is useful for holding the 2nd label's text and setting the first column's width is necessary, I think.

Comment: Well, I added two columns.
The problem is that the item has still the normal size/height, but it needs to be bigger.

Comment: You need to make the LV's Font large enough; do it in the designer or try `listView1.Font = new Font("Arial", 32f);` in the Form_load event.

Comment: Well ok, but the problem is now that the selection looks a bit boring. =) It is just one color, not as on top in the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55659/discussion-between-taw-and-trade).

Comment: @Trade: If you find the answer solves your problem, please accept it. (Somebody has upvoted the answer, which is nice. But _accepting_ it is much more important. Not so much because it earns the both of us a little reputation, but because it documents the problem as being solved.) To _accept_ an answer you must find the __checkmark__ to the left, below the arrows and click it. It will turn green then. If you leave this out, anybody who visits the post will believe that no useful solution has been found..

Comment: BTW: the problems in formatting were caused by a bug in the markdown rendering. Code after a list sometimes doesn't work, unless one inserts something else..

Comment: I know how to accept an answer. And the upvote, that was me ;)
But I hadn't finished yet.
The problem was that I did not know that I must apply a theme from uxtheme.dll to make the listview's items look like above.

Comment: _a theme from uxtheme.dll_ ah, interesting.

Comment: Yes, this DLL provides "SetWindowTheme" which allows to let it look better.
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]